# Unity mobile scrollrect too sensitive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i recently decided to make a 2D mobile game using Unity 5.
now i have a problem with the scrollrect. it is way to sensitive on mobile. on windows my buttons in the scrollcontent work perfect. but on my phone i have hard times to press the buttons in the scrollcontent. i think it is because the scrollrect scrolls before the touch ends so it registers as a drag, and not a touch.

i tried to search on the internet for this problem but is seems to be a 2-3 year old problem that should been fixed.

i hope someone has the answer for my problem,

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If the `ScrollRect` is too sensitive on mobile devices then you have to change the properties of `ScrollRect` such as `scrollSensitivity`,`elasticity`,`decelerationRate` on mobile devices. You detect if app is running on mobile device then you change the values. The code below should do it.You may need to change the values to your needs.

```
void Start()
{
  if (Application.isMobilePlatform)
  {
      ScrollRect scrolRect = GameObject.Find("GameObjectScrollRectIsAttachedTo").GetComponent<ScrollRect>();
      scrolRect.scrollSensitivity = 0.5f;
      scrolRect.elasticity = 0.05f;
      scrolRect.decelerationRate = 0.2f;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this answer has been deprecated.  I recommend https://stackoverflow.com/a/61105302/1889720.

Answer (score 3):

The actual question in hand here is how to stop the scrollview from scrolling from a very small amount of drag. This is particularly annoying on mobile devices, especially if you have a button in the scrollview, since the drag will cancel the button click.
Adding a threshold with a script is unnecessary, since the event system already has a drag threshold. change that to a higher value to reduce sensitivity.

A better solution for mobile, would be to get the dpi from the screen

```
GetComponent<EventSystem>().pixelDragThreshold = baseThreshold*Screen.dpi/baseDPI
```

and set the eventsystem dragthreshold to some value based off of that.

Comment: What is the value of baseDPI here? Did you initialize it earlier or do you use a formula for it?

Answer (score 1):

ok, i found a answer for my problem. after reading some more forums i came to the solution of add an event system. in the eventsystem i was able to modify the threshold, that did the trick.

Comment: lol posted 10 seconds after my answer. I actually think that modifying those values will solve your problem.

Comment: increasing 'Drag Threshold' of the Event System worked best for me. thanks